# How do I separate remote data access (via http) logic from the business logic?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm curious what would be the best design pattern to use in the following implementation: **I'm creating a small application to download an image from a website and set it as my background.**

I want to interface with a website to download an XML `Background.xml` file and also download another file (`Background.bmp`) which is hosted on this remote server. The file is a bitmap and the XML is metadata about the bitmap. After I download the file I would like to set it as my background. I would like to separate the file downloading code from the background setting code but I'm not sure which design pattern I would use.

This seems like a typical presentation/data/business application with the Form being the presentation layer, the background setter/XML parser being the business layer, and the downloader being the data layer. But I wasn't sure which design pattern I would use for the actual data access since it would be from a website and not a database (so DAO is possibly not right for this). I've also shopped the design patterns on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) but nothing seemed right. Is this something I could use MVC for?

**Data Layer**

```
public class DataLayer {
    public void DownloadFile() { 
        // download the file from http
    }
    public void GetXmlMetaData() { }
}
```

**Business Layer**

```
public class BusinessLayer {
    private static BusinessLayer m_instance = new BusinessLayer();  
    public static Instance BusinessLayer { get { return m_instance; }
    private BusinessLayer() { }

    public void SetNewWallpaper() { 
        // download the file from data layer
        // set it as the background
    }
    public String GetWallpaperInfo() { return String.Empty; }
}
```

**Presentation Layer**

```
public class PresentationLayer {
    public void HandleButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
        BusinessLayer.Instance.SetNewWallpaper();
    }
}
```

How would I separate the data access portion from the background setting logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm curious what would be the best design pattern to use in the
>   following implementation

Based on what criteria? Downloading a file and doing X with it, isnt  the same as building an aircraft maintenance and parts tracking system.  Complexity, software lifecycle, team size, budget, time frame, all influence the "best approach"

Once you know why you want to apply which software design principle, then it falls into place more easily.

> I would like to separate the file downloading code from the background
>   setting code 
>       but I'm not sure which design pattern I would use.

Why?  Yes this is good practice, but have a reason why to separate.  Reduce bugs, increase code reuse, facilitate better unit testing, removing dependencies, make maintenance easier, decoupling...
You can:

a) Putting all code in one method is one extreme.
 b) use many methods in a   class. a level up
 c) Separate classes in a project the next step. Basic OO
 d) Make separate projects in a solution.  More  design patterns
 e) Build Separate Solutions that   communicate.  The other extreme.

you are most likely looking at  C) or D) given your  preference to apply design principles.

The option you select  can have variants in its own right such as  dependency injection/Inversion of Control patterns. But im going to suggest you dont try and do that in up front. Sounds like overkill for your App.

> This seems like a typical presentation/data/business application

Yes it does, but 90+% of projects will be in some way.  Not much point having data you dont present. Not much point in a presentation with no data.

Given your Rep of nearly 2K at time of post you clearly can code.
So I'm going to suggest:
Build a Solution with 3 projects.

1. Data Access
2. The Business Layer
3. The presentation.
4. A core model  Project with Just simple classes (POCOs)  and basic object logic
5. Dependency Injection/Inversion of control

Consider 4 or 5 only if very keen, and DI/IOC is probably best left until you are happy with 1/2/3/4 type solutions.

Avoid referencing/calling the data access project from the Front End project.

The core model should not reference the other projects.

> Is this something I could use MVC for?

Yes, you could.  The frontend Project has a controller (or 2) The controller "calls" views in the Front-end project.  The Views only present and get data from user.  The Controller calls another layer . Eg Controller call Business Process layer with may make several calls to Data layer to get all required information and update it.

Take a look here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials if you want to know more about MVC.
The tutorials dont always "separate" cleanly as they concentrate on the MVC aspect.
Infact You will see data access in the middle of controllers. Which the presentor would never do in a real project.

A single project using a basic MVC pattern is enough for small one off apps. Multiple projects complicate the "demo" .  But imagine wanting a Windows WPF version of your app. And seeing Data access code in the MVC project. Not much re-use there. That explains better the type of reasons why separation is good.

Good Luck...

Answer (score 1):

You are at stage of patternization. A lot of people goes through this stage. It appears when you know about patterns, learned some of them and already want to apply it everywhere where it could be applyed.

Attempt to write code with some pattern only to implement some of them it's not the best practice. Do not write code for code itself. Try to solve bussiness task in simpliest cleaner manner that's the best approach. Patterns just should helps you to do that.

You are already separate the different layers of your code and that's great. Your architecture pretty straightforward and you close to MVC. I think you should stop at this point to not to increase complexity.

Concerning DAO it means Data Access Object. There is no any word about Database. DAO could provide you access to any source of data: database, cache, nosql storage, files, data warehouse (your case) etc. And this is great because you can dynamically change datasource for your application just switching between them if they implements unified interface.